# Your Site Visitors or Your Site’s Visitors?

Tags: grammar, nouns, possessives

Your *site/site’s* visitors are very active.

How is correct to write: **your site visitors** or **your site’s visitors**?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the possessive, it's required.

When the *your* is absent and you are using it as a noun phrase, *site visitors* would be fine, but not with the *your*. Remember, *your* modifies *site*, not *visitors* here (by default).

In case you have defined earlier the expression 'site visitors' as a contextual noun phrase, then *your site visitors* will be valid, though with a different meaning.